# Exporting with PHP/PHPMyAdmin

Tags: php, mysql, import, phpmyadmin

I'm having problems with exporting/importing a database,
it seems like that PHPMyAdmin won't export database-table-relation settings and I can't get my views to work.
any ideas what's wrong / how I can export anything related to the database?

I was trying to fully import the database by completely deleting first then create a new database and import from .sql file.

Comment: what version of PHP, MySQL, and phpMyAdmin are you using?

Comment: online server:
PHP/5.2.6-1 | MySQL-Client-Version: 5.0.51a | phpMyAdmin: v3.3.9.1
locally:
PHP/5.3.4 | MySQL-Client-Version: 5.0.7-dev | phpMyAdmin: v3.3.9.2
shouldn't matter or?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

1) On export option check custom option.

2) Search for "Object creation options" check "Add DROP TABLE / VIEW / PROCEDURE / FUNCTION / EVENT statement" option.

Let me know if this works for you.